# How to move items up or down a listbox in Tkinter without losing their selection?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the below code which creates a simple listbox and allows users to select the item and move them up or down the list, thereby rearranging the list.

The issue I have right now is every time I press "move up" or "move down", the action is performed correctly, but the cursor no longer stays selected. I have to re-select the item in order to perform the function again.

I tried configuring exportselection = False when setting up the listbox, but that did not work.

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_title("Animals")
        self._frame = None

class AnimalPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.controller = controller
        self.config(relief='sunken', borderwidth=2)
        self.pack(fill = "both", expand = False)
        tk.Label(self, text="This is the Animal Configuration Page").pack()

        self.animalList = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bear', 'Dolphin', 'Kangaroo']
        self.animalString = tk.StringVar(value=self.animalList)
        self.animalBox = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=self.animalString,
                                height=25, width=50, borderwidth=2)
        self.animalBox.pack()

        moveUpButton = tk.Button(self, text="Move Up", command=lambda: self.moveup())
        moveUpButton.pack()
        moveDownButton = tk.Button(self, text="Move Down", command=lambda: self.movedown())
        moveDownButton.pack()

    def moveup(self, *args):
        try:
            self.idxs = self.animalBox.curselection()
            if not self.idxs:
                return
            for pos in self.idxs:
                if pos==0:
                    continue
                text=self.animalBox.get(pos)
                self.animalBox.delete(pos)
                self.animalBox.insert(pos-1, text)
                self.animalList.pop(pos)
                self.animalList.insert(pos-1, text)
        except:
            pass

    def movedown(self, *args):
        try:
            self.idxs = self.animalBox.curselection()
            if not self.idxs:
                return
            for pos in self.idxs:
                if pos==0:
                    continue
                text=self.animalBox.get(pos)
                self.animalBox.delete(pos)
                self.animalBox.insert(pos+1, text)
                self.animalList.pop(pos)
                self.animalList.insert(pos+1, text)
        except:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    newFrame = AnimalPage(app, app)
    app.geometry("1200x700")
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use *selection_set* to retain the selected item, like so:

```
 def moveup(self, *args):
    try:
        self.idxs = self.animalBox.curselection()
        if not self.idxs:
            return
        for pos in self.idxs:
            if pos==0:
                continue
            text=self.animalBox.get(pos)
            self.animalBox.delete(pos)
            self.animalBox.insert(pos-1, text)
            self.animalList.pop(pos)
            self.animalList.insert(pos-1, text)
            self.animalBox.selection_set(pos-1)
    except:
        pass
```

And similarly for *movedown*.

Comment: PS. I couldn't help notice that the moveup and movedown functions are coded to cope with multiselections, yet the Listbox is created with the default selectmode (BROWSE) which only allows a single item to be selected.

Comment: Hi Mkam, thank you so much for the answer. It works really well (and bristola's answer worked too). I didn't know that there are different selectmodes - I'll look into which one allows for multiple selection. One last thing I noticed is using your answer, if I move for ex. Kangaroo to the top, I can no longer move it down. Only if I move Cat up 1 spot, then I can start moving Kangaroo down again.

Comment: Yes, movedown doesn't work as coded, because when moving an item down you need to check whether you've reached the BOTTOM of the list (you're checking whether you're in position 0, which is the TOP). Please see my second answer for the correct movedown code.

Answer (score 4):

In order to have the selection stay selected, you must actually select the correct index in the code since it is in a new location. Luckily, the box's *select_set(i)* does this. you would do this like the following:

```
def moveup(self, *args):
    try:
        self.idxs = self.animalBox.curselection()
        if not self.idxs:
            return
        for pos in self.idxs:
            if pos==0:
                continue
            text=self.animalBox.get(pos)
            self.animalBox.delete(pos)
            self.animalBox.insert(pos-1, text)
            self.animalList.pop(pos)
            self.animalList.insert(pos-1, text)
        self.animalBox.select_set(pos-1)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

The corrected code for *movedown* is:

```
def movedown(self, *args):
    try:
        self.idxs = self.animalBox.curselection()
        if not self.idxs:
            return
        for pos in self.idxs:
            # Are we at the bottom of the list?
            if pos == len(self.animalList)-1: 
                continue
            text=self.animalBox.get(pos)
            self.animalBox.delete(pos)
            self.animalBox.insert(pos+1, text)
            self.animalList.pop(pos)
            self.animalList.insert(pos+1, text)
            self.animalBox.selection_set(pos + 1)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: You're so awesome. Thank you mkam!

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code and realized that selecting 'up' on the topmost item in the list didn't do anything.  The following is rewritten to:

- enable calling of a single function (you just pass -1 for up and 1 for down when the function is called.)
- remove the *try* and *except* which makes for better code
- make the list item go to the bottom from the top if 'up' is chosen
- make the list item go to the top from the bottom if 'down' is chosen

  ```
    def move(self, num):
        #num is -1 for up and 1 for down
        self.idxs = self.animalBox.curselection()
        if not self.idxs:
            return

        for pos in self.idxs:
            text=self.animalBox.get(pos) #gets text
            self.animalBox.delete(pos) #removes text from list box
            self.animalList.pop(pos)  #removes text from list
            if pos==len(self.animalList) and num==1: pos=-1; #sets at beginning if at bottom and going down
            if pos==0 and num==-1: pos=len(self.animalList)+1; #sets at end if at top and going up
            self.animalBox.insert(pos+num, text) #inserts into list box
            self.animalList.insert(pos+num, text) #inserts into list
            self.animalBox.selection_set(pos+num)
  ```